# how to display images in the page.tpl.php with drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

i have theme it is name (car) and have image links in page.tpl.php and i want to display this image with short way
anyone can help me..the most of this ways to node.tpl.php but i need to display images with page.tpl.php

```
<img src="rightgallery/img/img1_thumb.jpg" alt="motherly" />
```

i try to add this code in template.php file

```
  // helper variable path to theme
function car_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
$vars['thefullpath'] = $GLOBALS['base_url'] . "/" . $GLOBALS['theme_path'];
}
```

and then print the path like this but still didnt work

```
<img src="<?php print $thefullpath; ?>rightgallery/img/img1_thumb.jpg"  alt="motherly"
```

>

Comment: What do you get as the output of your last snippet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there are 2 ways to do so directly from your theme's page.tpl.php (without the need to create a template preprocess function):

1- Using `<img>` tag:

```
global $base_path;
print "<img src='" . $base_path . path_to_theme() . "/img/img5.jpg' width='240' height='300' />";
```

2- Using Drupal's `theme()`:

```
print theme("image", array(
    'path'  => path_to_theme() . "'/img/img5.jpg",
    'width' => "240",
    'height' => "300",
));
```

References:

- [$base_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_path/7)
- [theme() function.](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7)
- [theme_image()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7).

Answer (score 1):

the right path like this

```
<li>
  <img src="<?php print  $thefullpath; ?>/rightgallery/img/img5.jpg" 
     alt="nature sent packing" width="240" height="300" />
</li>
```